# How to create component in render part from fetched API?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to fetch data from api and I used componentDidMount lifecycle for that, But I have a list in my view which need to be created from that API, so I use map function for received data to get all items and show in render part, But when I run my code I get
this.state.matchInfo.map in not a function

Please help me to solve this problem, I knew that componentDidMount will run after first render so I create an empty state first and hoped that after fetching data, component will render again and will show my data. but it keeps getting me the error

here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      userToken: '',
      userID: '',
      firstTime: true,  
      loading: true,
      showAlert : false,
      alertType : true,
      alertMessage : '',      
      animatedMatchBtn : new Animated.Value(1),      
      matchInfo: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {  
  this._bootstrapAsync(true);  
}

_bootstrapAsync = async (timeOutStat = null) => { 
  const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');  
  const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
  const userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID'); 
  await this.setState({
    userName: userName,
    userToken: userToken,
    userID: userID,
  })   
  if(timeOutStat) {
    this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        showAlert: true,
        alertType: true,
        alertMessage: ErrorList.matchMakingError
      });
    }, 20000)
  } 
  console.log('token', userToken)   
    await fetch(getInitUrl('getMatchInfo','',this.props.navigation.getParam('matchID', 0)), {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization : `Bearer ${userToken}`  
      }
    }).then(response => Promise.all([response.ok, response.status ,response.json()]))
    .then(([responseOk,responseStatus, body]) => {      //
      this.setState({loading : false});
      clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
      if (responseOk) { 
        console.log('match Info', body);
        this.setState({
          matchInfo : body
        })        
      } else {
        console.log(responseStatus, body);
        this.setState({
          showAlert : true,
          alertType : true,
          alertMessage : ErrorList[body.tag]
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};

render() {
    //console.log(puzzleSizes)
    let rows = this.state.matchInfo.map((item , index)=>{
      return 
      <MatchDetailBox
      />
    })
    console.log(rows)
   <View>
    {rows}
</View>
}
```

Comment: add a `return` before `<View> </View>`, since you have used `let rows = this.state.matchInfo.map()` implicit return wouldn't work. I know it won't solve your problem. I am looking at the cause of the issue now

Comment: of course, but it didnt solve the issue, I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this.setState() is asynchronous, it's not promisified hence it wont't work using promise's `.then()` or its syntactic sugar `async/await`. So there's no use for await in front of it. But I guess it creates a one tick delay.

Also why do you have `await` in front of fetch() and also `.then()` after that. Shouldn't either of them do?

The error `this.state.matchInfo.map is not a function` would occur only when `this.state.matchInfo` is not an array but you have initialized it to be one, so at any point of time matchInfo gets modified it must be becoming non-array like an object or something which doesn't have a native `.map()`.

Have you checked response coming from API? I hope this helps.

`this.setState({ matchInfo: body });`

Comment: Good answer. I think the api does not return an array for matchInfo, otherwise `map` would have worked for an empty array. Good points about the `setState` calls and the `await` weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapData = () => { 
     this.state.matchInfo.map((item , index)=>{
    return(
        <View>
            <MatchDetailBox />
            <View>
                {item}
            </View>
        </View>

    ) 
  })
}
render() {
    return {this.mapData()}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'a already doing this. am I right? because I had my fetch function in componentDidMount , I didn't get the difference